# Design for data-intensive web-page and search criteria

Tags: website-design, search, data

I am very much a UX noob, but I need to design a web-page to display a large amount of numeric data, presumably in a grid.  The users will be able to enter search criteria using the attributes shown in the grid.

One pattern I have seen is to have a pair of rows above the grid which contain the search mix/max criteria:

```
+----+----+----+
|    | A  | B  |
+----+----+----+
|min | 2  |    |
+----+----+----+
|max |    | 19 |
+----+----+----+
+----+----+----+
|    | 3  | 17 |
+----+----+----+
```

How do I lay out the page and how do I capture the minima and maxima? I like the sliders, but I think that to be usable they may be too wide for the column header

Comment: Paul, your question seems interesting, but I couldn't quite figure out what the question is, exactly :). Could you clarify? What is the specific problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I have 15 columns of (mostly) numeric data to display. I want to filter using number and date ranges. My question is how to lay out the page and how to capture the minima and maxima. I like the sliders, but I think that to be usable they may be too wide for the column header.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you right... I would do something like that:

[image]

Numbers under slider are editable on click and show their input field on hover.

Comment: I like this but I think that to be usable they may be too wide for the column header.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a column header, it can be placed anywhere on page. Fro example on left side of table, or above it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this implementation of data filtering possibilities. Sample a few of your datasets and try to match them to search, filter or min/max slider/select use cases. Are you doing reporting or trying to help people to find and filter the searched dataset?

- [jQuery Plugin DataTables - individual column filtering example](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter.html)
- [jQuery Plugin DataTables | Range Filter](http://www.datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html)
- [jQuery Plugin DataTables | Range Filter with slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373918/datatables-and-jquery-range-slider-to-filter-data)

Comment: That example is not capturing range data

Comment: Well range is builtin actually.